# compare year and month of date field to be greater than

Tags: python, django

I'm going to do this query:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
year=today.year
month=today.month
news=News.objects.filter(date__year__lt = year,date__month__lt=month)
```

Note:News object has a field named `date`
but I get this error:

```
Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?
```

what's your idea?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't append `__lt` onto to `__year` or `__month`. Only the last double-underscored bit is consider the qualifier, everything before it is treated as a traversal, i.e. Django will try to look up a field named `year` on join table named `date`, which is obviously not correct.

For something like this you'll need to just compare the date directly:

```
date = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
news = News.objects.filter(date__lt=date)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy,date field has the date and time and I wanna just compare date,the way U suggest is correct if the time be eliminated,how can I do this?

Comment: You can use that with a `DateField` or `DateTimeField`. If it's a `DateTimeField` the time compared will be implicitly midnight.

Comment: U mean I can't save time and date while I'm going to do such query on it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. All you wanted was news earlier than a particular month and year. For that, all you need to compare it with is a Python `date`. You could have also used `datetime.datetime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0)`, but that's unnecessary. Neither way actually affects what's returned by the query. Your `DateTimeField` is still a `datetime` even if you compared it with a `date` in the query.

Comment: sorry!I wanna compare day,too,s.th like this: News.objects.filter(date__exact=datetime.date(today.year, today.month, today.day))  ,here time is unimportant and it ruin my results.I hope I've clarified well.

Comment: So what is the problem with `date__lt = datetime.date.today()`?

Comment: date has time but datetime.date.today() doesn't have time then this cause to result desn't be correct.

Comment: so,I had no way out,I used datefield

Comment: @Asma: How is it incorrect? Again, when you compare a `datetime` with a `date`, the `date` is essentially converted into a `datetime` with the time being "00:00:00", a.k.a midnight or 12:00 AM, i.e. the very beginning of that day. It will return anything "less than" that date, which will be anything the previous day or earlier because it's midnight.

Answer (score 2):

Django has trouble with certain lookups when working through a relation (e.g. `date__year__*`). I think this is something they are working on for future versions.

Does this produce an acceptable result?

```
news = News.objects.filter(date__lt = datetime.date(year, month, 1))
```

Comment: great tip,your answer is correct,take a look at my top comment.

Answer (score 0):

One of way to filter data based on Date and month only in Django is

```
Sales.objects.filter(Date__month=month,Date__year=year)
```

Sales Model:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
Amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
Date = models.DateField()
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
VAT = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['id']

def __str__(self):
    return "{}-{}".format(self.Amount,self.Date)

def class_name(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__
```